# Prolog - Not returning desired Variable

Tags: prolog, return-value

I realised that my first question was too long and no one would understand it.

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670453/prolog-not-returning-desired-value) to a condensed simpler question that exhibits my problem in a shorter program.

[Condened Question Link] [Prolog - Not returning desired value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670453/prolog-not-returning-desired-value)

==================================================================================

I am trying to write a Brainf*ck interpreter in Prolog.

The function bf will take 3 strings. Only relevant parts of the code is as follows:

```
%Prog - string of BF program
%Input- string of inputs for the BF program
%Output - what the BF program will output

bf(Prog, Input,Output):- run(Prog, Input, Output).

run(Prog, Input, Output) :-
    create_mem(Mem),
    iterateBF(Prog,[],Mem,0, Input, Output).

%start by creating the memory space
create_mem(Memory) :-
    var(Memory), %check if it is uninstantiated variable
    create_mem(Memory,10000).

create_mem([],0) :- !.
create_mem([0|Tail],Size) :-
    NewSize is Size - 1,
    create_mem(Tail,NewSize).

%get memory value at ptr location
get_mem([Value|_],Value,0). %base case
get_mem([_|Tail],Value,Ptr) :-
  Ptr > 0,
    NewPtr is Ptr - 1,
    get_mem(Tail,Value,NewPtr).

%for adding a value to memory space
%need to mod with 256 due to the it being 8 bits to get the actual value.

increase_mem([Value|MemTail],[NewValue|MemTail],0) :-
    NewValue is (Value + 1) mod 256.
increase_mem([Head|Tail],[Head|NewTail],Ind) :-
    Ind > 0,
    NewInd is Ind - 1,
    increase_mem(Tail,NewTail,NewInd).

%iterateBF(Prog,[],Mem,0, Input, []).
%when reach the end of the the

iterateBF([],_,_,_,_,[]) :- !.
iterateBF([],_,_,_,_,_) :-!.
iterateBF(Instruction,Inst_Iterated,Mem,Ptr,Input,Output) :-

   checkInstruction(Instruction,Inst_Iterated,Mem,Ptr,Input,Output,
      NewInstruction,NewInst_Iterated,NewMem,NewPtr,NewInput,NewOutput),
    iterateBF(NewInstruction,NewInst_Iterated,NewMem,NewPtr,NewInput,NewOutput).


checkInstruction([Plus|ProgTail],Inst_Iterated,Mem,Ptr,Input,Output,ProgTail,Inst_Iterated,NewMem,Ptr,Input,Output) :-
        char_code('+',Plus),
        increase_mem(Mem,NewMem,Ptr), !.

%get the memory value at ptr
%Put into Output
checkInstruction([Period|ProgTail],Inst_Iterated,Mem,Ptr,Input,Output,ProgTail,Inst_Iterated,Mem,Ptr,Input,NewOutput) :-
    char_code('.',Period),
    NewOutput = [Output|Value],
    get_mem(Mem,Value,Ptr),!.
```

The above code will compile and only work for:

```
bf("+.","",Out).
```

SWI-Prolog will just return `true`, while I want it to return the value of `Out`.

Tracing it in SWI, whenever it returns to the call of `iterateBF(Prog,[],Mem,0, Input, Output)` in `run`, `Output` just loses its previous value.

You just need to pay attention to the following functions:

1. Run
2. iterateBF
3. checkInstructions

The rest are just for compilation sake.

Comment: @iccthedral thanks, im working on it.

Comment: @iccthedral here is the [SSCCE version of my problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670453/prolog-not-returning-desired-value). I hope you can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

your `checkInstruction([Plus|ProgTail],Inst_Iterated,Mem,Ptr,Input,Output,ProgTail,Inst_Iterated,NewMem,Ptr,Input,Output)` it's way too complex.

And indeed your problem it's that `Output` doesn't get correctly bound. But instead of a 'banal' correction, what about a general improvement:

Try to comment your code, what you expect it will do, and after done, possibly **simplify** it as far as possible.

Comment: thanks for your input. It is indeed that Output was not bound properly. I do not have a good grasp of its "partial answer"

Comment: Do you know how to start the debugger and follow single step? If you can then you'll get the chance to know what's happening to your variables...

Comment: I realised that the code I had above was too complicated, so I wrote a more succient program to exhibit the problem I was having [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670453/prolog-not-returning-desired-value). I was not appending my Output right, as well as having a wrong base case for iterateBF. Thanks for your concern and help though!