# Prolog - Not returning desired value

Tags: prolog, return-value

Here is a simple Prolog program to exhibit a problem that I currently have with my real code.

I am trying to write a Brainf*ck interpreter in Prolog, but it is not returning the right `Output`

I am running `bf("+.", Output)`

Expected Return - `Output = [1]`

Actual Return - `Output = []`.

`Output` looses its value when it returns to `iterateProg(Prog,Output)` in `bf2`.

Program is as follows:

```
bf2(Prog,Output):-
    iterateProg(Prog,Output).

iterateProg([],_):- !.
iterateProg(Prog, Output):-
    checkInstruction(Prog,Output, NewProg, NewOutput),
    iterateProg(NewProg, NewOutput).

checkInstruction([Plus|ProgTail],Output,ProgTail,Output):-
    char_code('+',Plus)
    %increase memory by 1 for printing later.
    .

checkInstruction([Period|ProgTail], Output, ProgTail, NewOutput):-
    char_code('.',Period),
    %take the value in memory from addition just now, we will assume it is 1
    append(Output,[1],NewOutput).
```

Comment: Please check my answer. I made a mistake in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predicate `bf2(Prog, Output)` has the meaning of: this program `Prog` correspond with this output `Output` - so the `Output` in the `bf2` predicate and also in `iterateProg` should contains the full output.

So in `checkInstruction` predicate, the first 2 arguments should contain the full program and the full output, and the last 2 arguments should contain the partial program and the corresponding partial output.

Therefore, you should append the `[1]` with `NewOutput`, to produce the final output in `Output` for the second rule of `checkInstruction` predicate. You should rename the `New...` with a different name - since it is actually the partial/"tail" program and corresponding output.

```
append([1], NewOutput, Output)
```

Note the **order** (I was inaccurate in the comment). `[1]` is the output for the current instruction, and it should precede the output of the instruction in `ProgTail`.

By the way, `bf2` predicate is unnecessary - since it call `iterateProg` predicate with exact same arguments.

Another thing is `iterateProg([],_)` should be `iterateProg([],[])` since an empty program should correspond with empty output. (The converse is not true, so you should never put a cut `!` here, if you have learned about it).

Comment: I have a another [prolog question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670798/prolog-list-of-charcodes-to-a-string-or-characters) if you are interested.