# inputting strings in prolog

Tags: string, prolog

I'm fairly new to prolog and was gven code to modify for homework. However i am stuck with inputting stings. I am aware that strings inputted in prolgo are lists of ascii codes.
ie, "abc" = [97, 98, 99]

This is the given code

```
accept(W) :- start(S), path(S, W).
path(S, []) :- final(S).
path(S, [H|T]) :- arc(S, H, N), path(N, T).
start(1).
final(3).
arc(1, a, 1).
arc(1, b, 2).
arc(2, a, 2).
arc(2, b, 3).
arc(3, a, 3).
```

This is a nondeterministic machine, with the knowledge of how strings are implemented, it was my assumption that the changing of the arc() facts to something like

```
arc(1, 97, 1).
arc(1, 98, 2).
arc(2, 97, 2).
arc(2, 98, 3).
arc(3, 97, 3).
```

would enable me to input a string of a's and b's, but that didnt work, can anyone help me with how i would do so?
Thank you

Comment: Also to input, you would write something like accept([list of a's and b's]), this is why i thought strings which are a list of ascii codes, would work with the modified arc.

Answer (score 0):

The data types in Prolog are numbers, variables, atoms and compound terms. Conceptually, Prolog thinks of strings as atoms, not lists of character codes. Have a read here for a (little) more detail: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Data_types

Also, if you would like to know more about conversion from characters to ASCII codes maybe have a read of this question: [Prolog - List of CharCodes to a String or Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670798/prolog-list-of-charcodes-to-a-string-or-characters)

You can test a list of a's and b's to see if they form a path by giving the predicate a list, for example:

```
accept([a,a,b,a]).
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

you could keep your grammar in the more readable form, and apply a conversion from character code to character:

```
3 ?- maplist(char_code, W, "aabaabaaa"), accept(W).
W = [a, a, b, a, a, b, a, a, a]
```

or

```
9 ?- read_line_to_codes(user_input, Cs), maplist(char_code, W, Cs), accept(W).
|: abab
Cs = [97, 98, 97, 98],
W = [a, b, a, b]
```

otherwise, the syntax for character literals is

```
arc(1, 0'a, 1).
arc(1, 0'b, 2).
arc(2, 0'a, 2).
arc(2, 0'b, 3).
arc(3, 0'a, 3).
```

after that change (or using your numeric representation, `arc(1, 97, 1).`)

```
% /home/carlo/prolog/stackoverflow compiled 0.01 sec, 23 clauses
10 ?- read_line_to_codes(user_input, W), accept(W).
|: abab
W = [97, 98, 97, 98]
```