# How to code a prolog program that does some operations on list

Tags: prolog, dcg

I want to program a list that uses only the characters {a, b}.

My objective is that Prolog returns true only if the list that the user enter contains n number of a, or at least one a but has to finish with one b only, no more and no less than just one b.

Example: `aaab` is correct, `aba` is incorrect, `b` is incorrect, `a` is incorrect.

Here's my code :

```
langage([]).
langage([a | S]):-
    langage(S).
```

The problem here is that it only accepts n numbers of a, and does not finish with b. But I want it to finish with the letter b.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: This is cross posted on SWI-Prolog Discourse forum. ([ref](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/how-to-program-a-list-in-prolog-that-can-contain-only-the-character-a-but-must-finish-with-the-character-b/4716?u=ericgt))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write it like this:

```
langage([a,b]).
langage([a | S]):-
    langage(S).
```

So your list needs to end on `a` and `b`, any leading `a`'s will be stripped by the second rule. Tested with SWISH:

```
?- langage([a,a,a,b]).
true;
false.

?- langage([a,b,a]).
false.

?- langage([a]).
false.

?- langage([b]).
false.
```

---

However, if you wanted to have a list starting with `a` with n>=1 follow up `b`, try this (not tested):

```
langageB([b]).
langageB([b| S]):-
    langageB(S).

langage([a| S]):-
    langageB(S).
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's exactly what i wanted.

Comment: But if I wanted to program a list in Prolog that must start with only one character a, and can contain n number of b? For example : a,b is correct, a,b,b,b,b,b is correct, a is incorrect, b,b,b is incorrect and a,a,b is incorrect. How should I do this please?

Comment: I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Very sorry to trouble you yet again, I still have three other problems that i can't code let's start with this one : How can I make a program that contains this time n numbers of a and n numbers of b, it's important to note here that the number a and b in the list must be equal, also the list must always start with a and finish with b, otherwise it's false. Exemple : [a,b] is true, [a,a,a,b,b,b] is true, [a,a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b,b] is true. But [a,a,b] is false, [a,a,a] or [b,b,b] is false and [a,b,b,b] or [b,b,a,a] is also false. Thank you very much for your help again.

Comment: @Nobody it is best to open a new question and provide your attempt. People here (including me) like to solve issues but just getting solutions will not help you understand prolog. So make a new question, show us what you tried and ask specific questions.

Comment: Alright, i'll show u what i did in a new question.

Comment: Here is the link of my new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70277140/how-to-program-a-list-in-prolog-that-must-contain-only-characters-a-and-b-and-o

Comment: hello sorry to bother you but after I added: langage([]). to your code, it's wrong now. Cause I want to make the list empty true in our case. 
langage([a,b]).
langage([a | S]):-
    langage(S).

Comment: @Nobody I guess you need an auxillary predicate like in the second case (`langage/1` and `langageB/1`). By just adding  `langage([]).` you allow 2 types of words: the words start with an arbitrary number of a's and end with either ab or nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Using Prolog's [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)-notation:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
:- use_module(library(double_quotes)).   % SWI, SICStus only

monlangage --> "ab" | "a", monlangage.

?- phrase(monlangage,L).
   L = "ab"
;  L = "aab"
;  L = "aaab"
;  L = "aaaab"
;  L = "aaaaab"
;  ... .
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36645725/772868) how to get such compact answers (default in Scryer and Trealla). Otherwise, you get answers like `L = [a,a,a,b]` etc.

To get some practice with Definite Clause Grammars it helps to reformulate the grammar a couple of times.  For example, there is some redundancy to be identified:

```
monlangage --> "ab" | "a", monlangage.
%               ^      ^
```

Both alternatives start with `"a"`!

```
monlangage_bis --> "a", ( "b" | monlangage_bis ).

?- phrase(monlangage_bis,L).
   L = "ab"
;  L = "aab"
;  L = "aaab"
;  L = "aaaab"
;  L = "aaaaab"
;  ... .
```

Now, are these languages really the same? Is above query sufficient to ensure this? Well consider

```
sonlangage --> "ab" | "a", sonlangage | "b".    % règle provocateur !

?- phrase(sonlangage,L).
   L = "ab"
;  L = "aab"
;  L = "aaab"
;  L = "aaaab"
;  L = "aaaaab"
;  ... .
```

Looks pretty much the same, yet,

```
?- phrase(monlangage, "b").
   false.
?- phrase(sonlangage, "b").
   true.     % unexpected
```

How can we identify such differences quickly? Inspecting the set of solutions as above did not help.  The real problem behind was that Prolog enumerated the solutions in an **unfair** manner.

What we can do is to enumerate all solutions/answers by length.

```
?- length(L,_), phrase(monlangage, L).
   L = "ab"
;  L = "aab"
;  L = "aaab"
;  L = "aaaab"
;  ... .
?- length(L,_), phrase(sonlangage, L).
   L = "b"      % caught!
;  L = "ab"
;  L = "ab"     % redundant (but not incorrect)
;  L = "aab"
;  L = "aab"    % idem
;  ... .
```

This will not find all the errors, but at least we can ensure that there are no differences up to a certain finite length.

Another way to reformulate `monlangage//0` would be to better outline that all sentences end with "b".

```
monlangage_ter --> "a", as, "b".

as --> "" | "a", as.
```

Or in a more generic fashion:

```
monlangage_quater --> "a", star("a"), "b".

star(NT__0) --> "" | NT__0, star(NT__0).
```

Comment: Nice to see others starting to add the `set_prolog_flag` and `use_module` for these DCG answers. It took me an extra 6 months of learning DCGs to figure out those were missing from answers posted here long ago. Thus adding the `DCG` tag here and noting [DCG info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dcg/info).

Comment: @GuyCoder: Only an extra half-year? It took me much more to realize that this C&M chapter is not only for linguists as I was told in 1986.

Comment: And then we wonder why there are so few people who will hang in to really understand the beauty that Prolog can bring.

Comment: @GuyCoder: Did you read *If you have difficulties installing `double_quotes.pl` as a library, simply put it into the directory of your other Prolog files and say: `use_module(double_quotes).`*?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868).

Comment: No, that again is a link that leads to a SO answer. This is what I was expecting. [http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/double_quotes.pl](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/double_quotes.pl). A simple click then the code.